# build python c extension for android

Tags: python, android, cross-compiling

I am trying to build a C++ module for Python on Android.  My host system is Ubuntu 22.04 on x64.  The issue I am running into is that it is unable to use the host python headers when I am targeting armeabi-v7a:

```
/usr/include/python3.10/pyconfig.h:17:12: fatal error: 'arm-linux-gnueabi/python3.10/pyconfig.h' file not found
#  include <arm-linux-gnueabi/python3.10/pyconfig.h>
```

What is the proper way of getting the proper headers?